# Optional group never matches

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The following is a simplified version of a problem I'm struggling with. I have this file:

```
1 H 200 OK.Content-Length: 2422 x
2 H 403 Forbidden.z
```

and I tried to get sed to match the HTTP Status and - if present - the content-length like so:

```
> sed -nEe 's,^.*H ([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+).*(Content-Length: ([0-9]+))?.*$,\1 \3,p' x
200 OK 
403 Forbidden
```

So the optional group never matches. If I make it non-optional by removing the question mark, it does match the content length, but it won't match lines without it:

```
> sed -nEe 's,^.*H ([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+).*(Content-Length: ([0-9]+)).*$,\1 \3,p' x
200 OK 2422
```

**How can I make sed give me the following output?**

```
200 OK 2422 
403 Forbidden
```

N.B. I also tried perl, which supports lazy matching (`.*?`), to no avail:

```
> perl -pe 's,^.*H ([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+).*?(Content-Length: ([0-9]+))?.*?$,\1 \3,' x
200 OK 
403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the `(Content....)` group is optional, in the greedy version, against:

> ```
> 1 H 200 OK.Content-Length: 2422 x
> ```

`^.*H ([ 0-9a-zA-Z]+)` matches `1 H (200 OK)`, then `.*` matches up to the end, and `(Content-Length: ([0-9]+))?` and the next `.*` both match the empty string at the end of the line.

In the non-greedy version, the first `.*?` tries to match as little as possible, and that's nothing, as the rest of the line (`.Content-Length: 2422 x`) does match `(Content-Length: ([0-9]+))?` that is nothing followed by `.*?$` everything up to the end of the line.

You'd need to make sure the first  `.*` after the first capture does not roll over a `Content-Length: \d+`, for instance using some negative look ahead at each step:

```
perl -lne 'print if
 s/^.*?H ([\s\w]+)(?:(?!Content-Length: \d+).)*(?:Content-Length: (\d+))?.*$/\1\2/'
```

Though you could simply do:

```
perl -lne '
  if (/H\s+([\s\w]+)(.*)/) {
    my $status = $1;
    print "$status" . ($2 =~ /Content-Length: (\d+)/ && " $1");
  }'
```

Or:

```
sed -nE 's/^.*H[[:space:]]+([[:space:][:alnum:]]+).*Content-Length: ([[:digit:]]+).*$/\1 \2/p;t
         s/^.*H[[:space:]]+([[:space:][:alnum:]]+).*$/\1/p'
```

That is, not try to do it in a single substitution.

Answer (score 0):

In sed regex is greedy. Your `.*` before `Content-Length:` already matched all remaining characters to the end. If you know that between the status and the length there's only a dot, then use `\.` instead.

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]+[ \t]+H[ \t]+([0-9]+[ \t]+[A-Za-z]+)\.(Content-Length:)?([ \t]+[0-9]+)?.*/\1\3/' file
```

One-liners are nice, but sed also has `//`: an if-like. Run below script with `sed -rf script file`.

```
s/^[0-9]+[ \t]+H[ \t]+([0-9]+[ \t]+[A-Za-z]+)/\1\n/
/\n.*Content-Length:([ \t]+[0-9]+).*/ s//\1\n/
s:\n.*::
```

Since sed reads by default only one line at a time from the file, `\n` can't be present from the data. As such it is safe to use as a temporary delimiter.